# Get value of a selected checkbox row in DatagridView

Tags: c#, checkbox, datagridview

I have a DatagridView which contains row and data. I've added checkboxs to select one of the row **(1)** and then generate a PDF with the data of the selected row **(2)** (see picture) :

[image: Screenshot of the DGV]

My code contains a part which check if checkbox is 1 or 0 and then I don't know how to get the data of the "checked row".. See

```
 private void button_generer_pdf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {       
        List<DataGridViewRow> rows_with_checked_column = new List<DataGridViewRow>();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGrid_factures.Rows)
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[column_action.Name].Value) == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("OK!"); // Just to check if it undestands I've checked the row
                //And then here I want to get highlighted data on the screenshot to create my Pdf
            }
        }
        //PDF Generation here
```

Comment: What is exactly the question?

Comment: Sorry if it was not clear, the question is : How to get now the highlighted data in the screenshot of the selected row so I can use these data to create a PDF (it is an invoice actually so I have to use the name of customer and total amount etc..)

Comment: How are you populating the data in the DGV?

Comment: @stuartd I use a query : `var requete_facturation = from r in bdd.client
                                             join c in bdd.facture on r.IDCLIENT equals c.CLIENT
                                             select new
                                             {
                                                 c.IDFACTURE,
                                                 r.NOM,
                                                 r.PRENOM,
                                                 c.TOTAL
                                             };`

Comment: The same way you got the data from your selection column row.Cells[column_action.Name].Value by changing it to be the right name so maybe "row.Cells["NOM"].Value

Comment: @BugFinder It worked, I don't know why I didn't thought about this way to do. Thank you :) Maybe put your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I will add it as an answer for you to mark as right then @Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same way you got the data from your selection column "`row.Cells[column_action.Name].Value`" by changing it to be the right name so maybe

```
row.Cells["NOM"].Value
```

or you can use the array number should you know it eg

```
rows.Cells[3].Value
```

Answer (score 0):

> hi my friend you can use this code for any cell or use a loop for all cells!!!

```
    public void ReadDataFromDataGridView()
    {
        string value = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["columnName"].Value.ToString();
    }
```